# Angular Universal - Exclude Route

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-universal

Is it possible to not use angular universal for certain route?
I want to use angular universal for my static pages.
And when i login to my application i dont want to use it. 
I want to exclude route with /app/*
How can i do that please?

Thank you very much

Here my server.ts

```js
 // These are important and needed before anything else
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
// Express Engine
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
// Import module map for lazy loading
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main');


app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'server'));

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'server')));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

UPDATE: I had this rule and he look like it work :

```
app.get('/app/**', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'));
});
```

Comment: You could add a rule to your webserver so that it does not transfer the request to nodejs if it starts with `/app/`

Comment: Thank you @David it look like it  work with that rule :

app.get('/app/**', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'));
});

Comment: I had to do `/admin**` to make it work because server would still try to pretender the request with `/admin` path.