# How to use ssr only for custom url with angular universal

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

geniuses!
I have a problem. I use @ng-toolkit/universal for SSR. But Universal render all of modules with components. How can I exclude some modules out of SSR and use the custom modules only for SPA?

P.S. I want to use nodeJS+express as fronted + proxy server.

Comment: Define some express routing for these modules

Comment: See here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52117185/angular-universal-exclude-route